# How to get position of pixel touched in android studio xml?

Tags: android, xml, position, touch, pixel

I'm trying to get the actual touch pixel of a background image of an android studio xml. I'm trying to start a new activity when touch position is in bounds of desired coordinates. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get x,y position of a specific pixel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926055/get-x-y-position-of-a-specific-pixel)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can set onTouchListener() on your layout with background image.

```
RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
mainLayout.setOnTouchListener(this); // in this case activity should implements  View.OnTouchListener
```

Then use something like that

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    Point touchPlace = new Point();
    touchPlace.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
}
```